# Sorl-thumbnail view returning thumbnail - without template tags

Tags: python, django, performance, thumbnails, sorl-thumbnail

I have a question concerning thumbnails generated using sorl-thumbnail in django.

**My model:**

```
from django.db import models
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField
from project.settings import UPLOAD_DIR

class MyImage(models.Model):
    file = ImageField(upload_to=UPLOAD_DIR)
```

**My view:**

```
from base.models import MyImage
from sorl.thumbnail import get_thumbnail
from django.http import HttpResponse
from project.settings import UPLOAD_DIR
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def thumbnail(request, filename, width, height):
    path = UPLOAD_DIR + '/' + filename
    image = get_object_or_404(MyImage, file=path)
    dim = '%sx%s' % (width, height)
    im = get_thumbnail(image.file, dim, crop='center', quality=90)
    return HttpResponse(im.read(), content_type='image/jpg')
```

**And urls:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from base.views import thumbnail
from django.conf.urls.shortcut import urlpatterns

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^100x100/(?P<filename>\S+)/$', thumbnail, {'width': 100, 'height':100, }),
)
```

It works as expected, i.e. it generates thumbnails on the fly based on filename given in the url. I need it, because I need a simple way to generate thumbnails without using django tags. It would be much easier for copywriters to create a thumbnail using simple address, like:

```
<img src="/thumbnail/100x100/myimage.jpg" />
```

than:

```
{% thumbnail "http://mydomain.com/uploads/myimage.jpg" "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" />
{% endthumbnail %}
```

What do you think about this idea? What should I change in this code? Or maybe I should try to find other way to solve this issue?